Handling Multiple Embedding Types in LangChain for RAG Applications
I'm building a RAG application using LangChain. It works well with one type of embedding in my database, generating specific code based on context. Now, I want to add support for Q&A. I've implemented Q&A by creating embeddings for various common questions, but sometimes my code generation fails because the top three similar embeddings are all Q&A.
Is there a way to retrieve context from two separate indexes using LangChain?
